# How to set the physical length from an axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a command to set the length of an axis? I do not mean the range! Independently from the values, the range from the axis or other factors, I want to set its length. How can I do that?
Something like `plt.yaxislenght(20)`?

Comment: What's the goal? Changing the aspect ratio of a figure? I couldn't imagine why you'd want an axis that is much shorter than your data range, and longer can be achieved by setting the range.

Comment: My goal is to plot several subplots, which have the same axis-lenght (thats automatic). But for specifc reasons I want to set this lenght. I just need to set the lengt independly from any other factors

Comment: The physical length of an axis is directly dependent on the figure size and the margins between figures and borders you have set. Changing just the length (which might be possible) will likely mess up the layout. Why don't you tell us why you want to do this?

Comment: as said, the reason why I want to do this, is because I want the physical length independ from any other factors. So for example `plt.tight_layout()` changes the length, or a legend "beside" the plot also changes the length...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a specific way to set an axis length of axes generated by *e.g.* `plt.subplots`. You can use [`ax.set_aspect(num)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect), but this adjusts the aspect ratio, and therefore will change both axes in a dependent way.

You can however use [`ax = plt.axes([left,bottom,width,height])`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes) to add individual subplots in whatever positions you like. This should allow you to achieve what you want, but will be tedious because you need to place each subplot manually.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is tricky due to the way that mpl works underneath.  Most of the artist are specified in units that are not on-screen units (data, axes, or figure space: see [transfrom tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/transforms_tutorial.html)).  This gives you a good deal of power/flexibility as *most* of the time you want to work in one of the relative sets of coordinates, however the cost is if you want to set 'absolute' sizes of things you end up having to do it indirectly.

If you want you axis to be a fixed length (in display units) between figures, then you need to control the size of you axes (in figure units) by hand (via [`fig.add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)) and then use `fig.set_size_inches` to set the size of your over-all figure.  By tweaking these values you can get what you want.